# problems with maintaining session over a hidden cross posting to an iframe inside a modal jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, forms, session, iframe, dialog

I am trying a hidden FORM post to an iframe in a dialog to carry on my checkout. 
Its the classical scenario of filling up a shopping cart and open a window with the transferred cart to checkout elsewhere (checkoutUrl on different server).

```
var form = $('<form>').attr({
    id : 'checkoutform',
    name : 'checkoutform',
    method : "post",
    enctype : "multipart/form-data",
    action : checkoutUrl,
    target : "checkout"
}).appendTo('body');
$('<input>').attr({
    type : 'hidden',
    name : 'osCsid',
    value : osCsid
}).appendTo(form);
var iFrame = $('#iframe');
if (iFrame.length == 0) {
    $('<iframe name="checkout" id="iframe" src=""></iframe>').appendTo('body');
    iFrame = $('#iframe');
}
iFrame.dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    position : [ 'center', 'center' ],
    dialogClass : 'shit-theme',
    closeOnEscape : true,
    modal : true
});
form.submit();
iFrame.dialog('open');
form.remove();
```

When I check my netlog I see many extra requests while loading the iframe:

```
Name         Method Status  Type       Initiator        Size   Time     Receiving     
checkout.php GET 302        text/html jquery.js:5763    542B    142ms   38ms
login.php    GET (canceled) undefined http://xdmhost/checkout.php 13B   123ms   
checkout.php GET (canceled) undefined jquery.js:5763    13B 3ms 
checkout.php GET (canceled) undefined jquery.js:5763    13B 3ms 
checkout.php GET (canceled) undefined jquery.js:5763    13B 5ms 
checkout.php GET (canceled) undefined jquery.js:5763    13B 31ms    
checkout.php GET (canceled) undefined jquery.js:5763    13B 21ms    
checkout.php POST 302       text/html Other            542B 134ms   93ms41ms
checkout.php GET 302        text/html jquery.js:5779    541B    194ms   63ms131ms
```

All I wanted to do was to POST to the checkout, which should cause a redirect to the login.
Whats going on here? Any ideas anyone?

Comment: in chrome this is kind of working with the dreaded message
"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL from frame with other URL".
however, with weird scrollbars

Comment: in firefox this message does not not show up

Comment: i have to put minwidth and minheight for the iframe in CSS 
AS WELL AS into the options of the dialog to make it works.
still left with the failing post from the loaded page after :(

Comment: dont use a src tag for the iframe, additional HTTP requests will confuse session creation

Comment: I gave up on the iframe and are using window.open() instead.
TOO MUCH HAZZLE!